# Cannot connect devices via bluetooth with Ubunutu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my Sony bluetooth headset, but my computer can't see them. On earlier versions of Ubuntu, I never had problems connecting them on Windows.

Now that I am running 11.10, my bluetooth mouse works, my phone doesn't connect, and my headset will not show up on the devices list.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with 11.10 with Bluetooth connecting to my Galaxy S (as well as SD card mounting in read only mode and showing corrupted files). I'm on a older HP dv6768se and the only fix I reached was uninstalling the Linux 3.0 kernel in 11.10 with the older 2.6.39 kernel for Oneiric. Bluetooth issue solved instantly. Lucid's kernel (2.6.31) was the last one that fully worked on my system in terms of the SD card issue. I'll try to install that next.

Answer (score 0):

I have had more luck with the `blueman` package in setting up my bluetooth devices than using `bluez`.  There are two competing managers, and sometimes one works better than the other.

Once you have your device connecting you may need to enable the device for audio in the pulse audio configuration.  I find the `pavucontrol` program gives me easy access to the settings needed.

Answer (score 0):

installing blueman solved my issue in 12.04 LTS. Thank You! My Emerson wireless headset would pair up but not appear in sound preferences and would not work.Everything works great now.